# Delete exact matches

Tags: excel, vba

I need Excel to delete columns as long as the header is NOT "Event Notes."
For related purposes, I found and successfully used the InStr function to find certain headers and delete the columns. But now I just want it to, starting at the end, delete columns until it finds THE EXACT STRING "Event Notes."
So far, I've had it delete EVERYTHING that didn't contain Event Notes; now it's finding "Event Notes Dates" and exiting the For loop.

Thanks a bunch for any assistance!

```
For iCounter = myWorksheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, myWorksheet.Cells(1, iCounter).Value, "Event Notes") = 1 Then
        Exit For
        Else
        myWorksheet.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
Next iCounter
```

Comment: change 'If InStr(1, myWorksheet.Cells(1, iCounter).Value, "Event Notes") = 1 Then' to 'If myWorksheet.Cells(1, iCounter).Value = "Event Notes" Then'

Answer (score 1):

following my comment, you should simply compare the range value to the "target" one

As per this little revision of your code

```
With myWorksheet ' reference your sheet. 
    For iCounter = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(1, iCounter).Value = "Event Notes" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                .Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
    Next iCounter
End With
```